# Can we control whether our app shows in the Google Drive Android app

Tags: google-drive-api

We have a couple of Google Drive apps that can be installed through the Chrome Web Store. In the latest update of the Google Drive app for Android, we noticed that users of this app have the option to use our app from the "Open With" menu (indicated as "open in web browser"). The issue is that our web app is not yet compatible with certain mobile browsers (especially phones). Can we prevent our app from appearing in this list until we address the browser compatibility issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app will show up in the "Open With" menu for those file types you listed when registering the app: https://developers.google.com/drive/register#setting_mime_types_and_extensions

You can leave those fields blank to prevent your app from showing up in the "Open With" menu, but please note there is no way to only show up in desktop browsers and not in mobile browsers.